# Heroku failed to load ./.env

Tags: heroku, webpack, environment-variables, dotenv

## My Problem

I am having trouble loading my environment variables on Heroku production.
When pushing to Heroku I get following error message during the build script:

```
Failed to load ./.env.
```

---

## Current Setup

I am using a `.env` file in the root of my app locally. I can succesfully load my environment variables using the `dotenv-webpack` plugin as follows:

```
//webpack.config

const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')
module.exports = {
  // other settings...
  
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
  ]
};
```

Loading the environment variables:

```
//server.js

require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env.MY_VARIABLE);
```

This works like a charm locally, but fails on Heroku.

> Note: My config vars have been set on Heroku, so that's not the problem.

---

## What I tried

I have already tried to force load the `.env` file from the root of my app like this:

`new Dotenv({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, './.env') });`

Someone also pointed out that the Heroku environment might be system wide environment variables so I tried to load them using:

`new Dotenv({ systemVars: true });`

Neither of these attempts worked for me.

---

## My guess

I have noticed that Heroku saves their `.env` file under `./tmp/build_someRandomBuildId/.env`. My guess is that the `.env` file is not on the root of the directory, hence why dotenv can't find it. There is also no way to hardcode the location of this file in my Webpack configuration as the build ID is randomized with every build. Is there a way to tell Webpack to look for the file in a dynamic location?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node JS environment variables and Heroku deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109813/node-js-environment-variables-and-heroku-deployment)

Comment: Not really, setting the environment variables in Heroku worked, it's loading them in production that failed as the .env file on Heroku is in a dynamically generated directory, so I can't point directly to it in my webpack.config. I did manage to find the solution though, I'll post the answer here when I get back from work. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: "as the .env file on Heroku is in a dynamically generated directory"—I'm not sure that I understand this. There shouldn't _be_ an `.env` file on Heroku. The whole point of `.env` files and libraries like `dotenv` is to set environment variables, but Heroku's config vars to this directly. `.env` files are mostly useful for development and shouldn't be included in the code you push.

Comment: You are right, I misinterpreted the error. Webpack was looking for an .env file in that dynamically generated directory. It obviously didn't find it, because there was no .env file as you stated. Hence the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Today i stumbled upon this problem, i tried several solutions but none worked. My App was working locally but in production mode (heroku) it was not loading process.env correctly.

then i found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack

```
//webpack.config.js
  plugins: [
      new Dotenv({ systemvars: true }),
  ],
```

Just setting systemvars to true does the trick..
For now I have tested this using different keys for the .env file and the heroku dashboard; They are not connected, and they replace themself correctly in production or dev mode.

Use the package "dotenv-webpack" instead of "dotenv".

I hope this saves some time to anyone facing the same problem

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the solution, leaving this here for others who have the same problem as I did.

I used `dotenv-webpack` to set my environment variables locally, which worked like a charm. Heroku on the other hand sets their environment variables automatically, so there is no need to set them yourself. There is no need to look for a .env file. All I had to do was split up my webpack.config in 2 separate files.

```
//webpack.dev

require('dotenv').config();

plugins: [
  new Dotenv()
],
```

Load .env file locally.

```
//webpack.prod

require('dotenv').config();

plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'YOUR_VARIABLE': JSON.stringify(process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE),
    }
  });
]
```

Get your environment variables from Heroku and write them to your own process.env

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Webpacks, the idea's solution is similar to the accepted answer.
Heroku works on "production" mode by default, so if the problem in Heroku is with Dotenv (which should not be used anyways in Heroku), disable the use of Dotenv in production time like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') { 
   require('dotenv').config() }
}
```

...and then, access env variables just by doing:

```
var someVar = process.env.SOME_VARIABLE;
```

Don't forget to set the environment variables on Heroku first by using Console Commandline in your app's dashboard, or with an app.json file.